# Inter task communication, is Service Discovery the way to go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I am using `ECS` with 1 service that runs multiple tasks. The tasks should be able to communicate with each other. I made it work by reading out the `eth1` network value, which corresponds to the private ipv4 address. With that value, tasks can talk to each other. I assume that this IP address never changes though, is this correct?

While googling other solutions, Service Discovery pops up. Now I am wondering, did I re-invented the wheel or is Service discovery used for communication among services and what I did was okay?

Comment: Yes you basically reinvented Service Discovery.

Answer (score 2):

> did I re-invented the wheel or is Service discovery used for communication among services and what I did was okay?

You re-invented the wheel.

> I assume that this IP address never changes though, is this correct?

That's incorrect. The IP can change, and probably will change, every time that task is replaced due to a deployment, due to auto-scaling, and due to any sort of task failure that causes ECS to automatically replace the task.

Comment: Just to clarify before I dive into Service Discovery/Connect, the docs are saying this: `Amazon ECS Service Connect provides management of service-to-service communication as Amazon ECS configuration`. But this should work for task-to-task communication as well?

Comment: Actually, re-reading your question I'm confused what you are doing. You have multiple instances of a single task, and those instances need to talk to each other? Do they each have to be aware of all the other instances somehow?

Comment: I am learning ECS just for a week now so I am not sure if it makes sense what I am doing, but I just want want to make a highly available webserver which can autoscale. I can configure everything I need in the task definition tab (auto scaling, load balancer). Then, within a single service, I assumed that spinning up multiple tasks will do the job. So I got the same server code running on multiple tasks within 1 service within 1 cluster. Is this okay or horrible? I really do not know. When user A wants to send a message to user B on a different server thus task, I need communication for tasks.

Comment: "When user A wants to send a message to user B on a different server thus task, I need communication for tasks" That should happen via something like a shared Redis server and pub/sub, or via a shared ActiveMQ or RabbitMQ server (or other message broker). The servers shouldn't be talking directly to each other to send user messages in a distributed system. On a load balanced web server it doesn't even make sense for a user to be *on* a specific server. Your web servers should be stateless and each request from a user should be handled by a random server.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I am running websocket servers which are stateful per definition. I currently save the private ipv4 address for the current server for each user that is connected and make http calls to a different server when a user is online at a different server. Then, that other server can send the message through the websocket. I can use MQ's but I do not think that makes anything easier. Anyway, what do you think about the task setup, is it common, or should I use more services? I assume you can just put everything in 1 service and have multiple tasks. Or is that wrong?

Comment: It's not a common task setup on AWS as it does not take advantage of AWS scalability and you can't really have ephemeral servers with your setup. Also, AWS Load Balancers support load balancing web sockets. You can have web sockets that are not stateful. Web Sockets are not really stateful per definition. Or at least, the state isn't required to be stored on the individual web servers.

Comment: Hmm one more question, can you please elaborate 'as it does not take advantage of AWS scalability' within my current setup? Can't I just spin up more tasks, that will scale right?

Comment: Forcing each user to always use a single server means that you can't auto-scale up and down as needed. Your load will potentially be unbalanced between servers, and you won't be able to scale down without messing up the session of all the users tied to that server.